# how to display a dial pad

Tags: android

how would I open the Dialpad and get the Number that the User like to call.
So I can do a check with it before I dial it from my Source?

If possible, with a small example.

Thanks
Anshuman

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this  code

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dial_number));
startActivity(dial);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:6365551212")));
```

see this [link](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/19/accessing-the-dialer/) for help.

Comment: yeh its working..actually i have used tabs.and on click of tabs it open but in another window but i open it in the same window below the tabs..so how that can be done..moreever once the dialpad open..when i go back and again click the tab it doesnt open..so how can i solve that problem..

Comment: This is opening the default dialing activity of android if you want to show it in the same window , you have to create your own custom layout and that will be very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean under dial pad telephone number entering, you can just use this one:

```
EditText editText=new EditText(context);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

so each time user will try to enter data - dial pad softkeyboard will appear on screen